# How to do a condition check and return a custom object when using a Promise?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have created a provider that will handle all firebase db related calls. If the method getUser is written as foll. then it returns the object (note that .once is a promise).

```
    getUser()
          {
            return firebase.database().ref(`/users/`)
            .once('value', dataSnapshot => {dataSnapshot.val();
            });
          }
```

However, if the object is null, then it returns a null and I have to handle this at the page level as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {         
    this.dbcon.getUser().then(dbvalue=>{
      if(dbvalue.val()){
     //..do soemthing.. 
     }      
    });
```

Ideally I would like the provider to either return a valid object or something like {sorcode:''}, but not null. Any advise to do this at the provider level will be helpful.

I tried implementing this at the provider level and was expecting it to return hard coded object {sorcode:''}. But it just returns null.

Code on page:

```
  ngOnInit() {         
    this.dbcon.getUser().then(dbvalue=>{
      console.log(dbvalue.val());
    });       
  }
```

Code in provider (note that .once is a promise):

```
   getUser()
  {
    return firebase.database().ref(`/users/`).once('value', dataSnapshot => {
           if (dataSnapshot.val()==null)
           {
              {sorcode:''};
           }
           else
           {
              dataSnapshot.val();
           }
    });
  }
```

If I use the 'return' keyword within the IF loop, and not before calling the promise (as shown below), then it gives an error on the page as: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Code in provider:

```
   getUser()
  {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/`).once('value', dataSnapshot => {
           if (dataSnapshot.val()==null)
           {
              return {sorcode:''};
           }
           else
           {
              return dataSnapshot.val();
           }
    });
  }
```

If I use the 'return' keyword within the IF loop, and also before calling the promise (as shown below), then it still gives the original issue - returns null when the object does not exist.

Code in provider:

```
       getUser()
      {
               return firebase.database().ref(`/users/`).once('value', dataSnapshot => {
var x=dataSnapshot.val();
               if (x==null)
               {
                  return {sorcode:''};
               }
               else
               {
                  return dataSnapshot.val();
               }
        });
      }
```

Comment: I guess you are missing the `return` statement

Comment: There is a return at beginning of the method. I think that should suffice?

Comment: No. there are two more missing... Or you write it like so: `dataSnapshot => dataSnapshot.val() == null ? {sorcode:''} :  dataSnapshot.val() `

Comment: If once is a promise dont you return that promise that you have to subscribe?

Answer (score 0):

The are `return` statements missing.

either:

```
return firebase.database().ref(`/users/`).once('value', dataSnapshot => {
       if (dataSnapshot.val()==null)
       {
          return {sorcode:''};
       }
       else
       {
          return dataSnapshot.val();
       }
});
```

or

```
 firebase.database().ref(`/users/`).once('value', dataSnapshot =>
   dataSnapshot.val() == null ? 
     {sorcode:''} :
     dataSnapshot.val()
 );
```

**UPDATE**

From [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) »returns firebase.Promise[…]«. So it should probably be (?):

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/`).once('value').then(dataSnapshot => <return stuff here>);
```

As it seams, the second argument is a »success callback«

Comment: In the 2nd code (after the 'or' line) are you missing the return keyword?

Comment: I have tried both options and the console.log still returns null

Comment: In the 2nd code is no return needed, because it´s a inline statement not a block. Inline statements always return a value and this value is also returned by the lambda. Block-Statements have no return value unless you explicity "return" it.

Comment: OK, but the page level console.log is still returning null. What could be the issue?

Comment: If once is a promise dont you return that promise that you have to subscribe?

Comment: Hello @philipp, there is no need to use '.then', because the '.once' itself returns a promise. Also, your syntax of using '.once' is incorrect as 'dataSnapshot' has to be defined within the brackets there isnt it? Also, then how do you write an IF condition to return an empty object if null (this is the main question - that is - how to return a custom object from a promise)?

Comment: It was just a shot in the dark… A Promise does not return a value, it does represent a value. Everything you pass to `resolve()` is that represented value, in case it is another »`thenable`«, its value passed to `resolve()` will become it. So if your Promise does not represent the right value, there must be something wrong with the value passed to `resolve()`.